# What's the max number of folders nested in an ExtJS Application?

Tags: model-view-controller, sencha-cmd

Well, turns out I have an ExtJS application. My views folder structure (if not the best), is this:

CE\app\view\process\Pre

OK, inside this folder, I created some components in some other folders, such as:

- CE\app\view\process\Pre\StudentData\Tabs\GeneralDataTab.js
- CE\app\view\process\Pre\StudentData\Tabs\AddressDataTab.js
- CE\app\view\process\Pre\StudentData\Tabs\SchoolDataTab.js
- CE\app\view\process\Pre\ParentData\Common\DataPanel.js

I define all of these componentes like this:

```
Ext.define("CE.view.process.Pre.StudentData.Tabs.GeneralDataTab", {
//some code to define and create my class
});
```

According to my research, I must name my class with the original folder structure, separared by dots.

Everything was fine while I was developing, but once I executed SENCHA CMD BUILD to test the results, I got this error:

> Couldn't find "Tabs" of undefined/Couldn't find "Common" of undefined

I checked many times the paths, the names and everything was OK.

So, I remove the last folders (Tabs/Common):

- CE\app\view\process\Pre\StudentData\GeneralDataTab.js
- CE\app\view\process\Pre\StudentData\AddressDataTab.js
- CE\app\view\process\Pre\StudentData\SchoolDataTab.js
- CE\app\view\process\Pre\ParentData\DataPanel.js

And voila! My application was working.

Everything happened after I ran `SENCHA CMD BUILD`, 'cause not even with `SENCHA CMD BUILD TESTING` I got this error.

Do you know if I mustn't nest that much folder structure in a Sencha ExtJS app?

I know I can define paths in the `paths` configuration of the application. I tried this, and renamed my classes, but It didn't work either.

Do you thing I did something wrong? Is it a bug of Sencha CMD? I'm using the version 4.0.1.45.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**:

I would like you to let you know that I resolved this problem, and I hope this could help you too.

In fact the problem wasn't the nested folders but the name of the classes.

In my `Application.js` file I added a new path, like this:

```
paths: {        
   //...
  'ProcessViews' : '../CE/app/view/process',
},
```

And now my classes name look like this:

```
Ext.define("ProcessViews.Pre.StudentData.Tabs.GeneralDataTab", {
//some code to define and create my class
});
```

And now I don't get any error message and the application runs OK.

So, looks like a class name can't be that long. If you need it to, then you should use a path defined in the `Application.js` to make a shorter name. :)

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly you want to come to know? About nested folder structure or your build issue ?

Comment: I doubt it's a bug in Sencha Cmd. More than likely something is misspelled. Keep an eye on your browser's JavaScript console when you run the app, I bet you'll see a warning about having to synchronously load a file or an error about something missing.

Comment: Hi! @MohitSaxena, what I want to know is if ExtJS App only supports certain maximum of nested folders or if the names of the classes can't be too long. In fact, my folder structure was the one to triggered the problem. `sencha cmd build` ran without problems, but it did something weird to the resultant `app.js` due the multiple folders nested.

@arthurakay, I checked and re-checked the console looking for a warning about the synchronously load, but no message like that was shown.  I made sure all classes had their `requires`

Comment: Check my edited post. I found the fix to this unusual problem :)